# Wish based tools (git-gui, gitk) showing broken/black UI on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-monterey

Wish based tools for instance git-gui and gitk are showing a black/broken screen after upgrading to macOS Monterey:

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the Tcl/Tk version (8.5) shipped with macOS Monterey is broken.

A possible fix:

#### use the version shipped with Homebrew

Assuming [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is already setup, do:

```
brew upgrade
brew install tcl-tk
```

Then setup a link to the new version of wish:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s ../Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.12/bin/wish wish
```

Eventually replace 8.6.12 with the version exposed by:

```
brew info tcl-tk
```

Restart your terminal and all wish-based utilities should work well!

Comment: I've seen system Tcl being broken (in a different way) with one of the first macOS Big Sur updates, then fixed with the next update... And then they did it again in Monterey? Didn't they are expected to test what they ship to end-users? Very strange way to "deprecate" a tool - deletion would be better than shipping a broken system tool...

Comment: You'll need to add /usr/local/bin to your PATH env variable (superseding wherever old `wish` binary was). Once I did that, I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a link that brew is unable to manage correctly

```
ls -l /usr/bin/wish

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Jan 22 08:42 /usr/bin/wish -> wish8.5
```

I have found this workaround

```
brew tap-new --no-git $USER/local-tap-git-2-32
brew extract --version=2.32 git $USER/local-tap-git-2-32
brew install git@2.32
/usr/local/opt/git@2.32/bin/git --version
brew link --overwrite git@2.32

brew tap-new --no-git $USER/local-tap-tcl-tk-8-6-10
brew extract --version=8.6.10 tcl-tk $USER/local-tap-tcl-tk-8-6-10
brew install tcl-tk@8.6.10
brew link --overwrite tcl-tk@8.6.10
```

And then run gitk with

```
/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk@8.6.10/bin/wish  $(which gitk)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an supplement for existing **Homebrew-based** solutions, the below is the **MacPorts-based** one, just 2 steps needed:

Firstly check system information:

```sh
$ uname -v
Darwin Kernel Version 21.3.0
$ port -v
MacPorts 2.7.2
```

**Step 1**: Install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/), since XOrg window system is **not** shipped by default on macOS 12(Monterey),

```sh
$ Xorg -version

X.Org X Server 1.20.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
...
```

**Step 2**: Install Tcl and Tk:

```sh
# Check if it is newer than 8.5
$ port info tcl
tcl @8.6.12 (lang)
...
$ port info tk@8.6.12
tk @8.6.12 (x11)
...


# Install
$ sudo port install tcl@8.6.12
...
$ sudo port install tk@8.6.12
...


# Check installation folder. (Might need to open a new Terminal)
$ ls -l $(which tclsh)
/opt/local/bin/tclsh -> tclsh8.6
$ ls -l $(which wish)
/opt/local/bin/wish -> wish8.6
```

Open *wish* window: (Here should be an **non black/broken** window)

```sh
$ wish
```

Done.