# How to compile a custom Tcl/Tk 8.6.12 version for macOS Monterey to avoid using Homebrew

Tags: git, macos-monterey, tcl

When I run `gitk`, Wish is displaying a broken/black window on macOS Monterey 12.6. [broken Wish window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upTc3.png)

I read from this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1696372/wish-based-tools-git-gui-gitk-showing-broken-black-ui-on-macos-monterey) that the Tcl/Tk version (8.5.9) shipped with macOS Monterey is broken and I would like to fix my problem by installing a newer Tcl/Tk version (8.6.12), but avoid using Homebrew.

I found a [web interface](http://kitcreator.rkeene.org/kitcreator) from KitCreator, which allows for compiling a custom Tcl/Tk package, but I have no clue, what options I should include (which tick boxes).

Does anyone know what a sensible selection of options would be for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a pre-compiled macOS version of tcl/tk v8.6.9 from ActiveState https://platform.activestate.com/danac/ActiveTcl-8.6/distributions - this is free for individual use.

This version works for wish (e.g. gitk) on my Monterey macbook.

NB the link to tclsh needs a little work to stop it from using the macOS installed version which I have not bothered to do.